# Cannot show image using php variables as the source code

Tags: php, html

I would like to show the image from the web server that is saved as mergedphoto/(userid).jpg

PHP part

`session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$txt_idno = $_SESSION['txt_idno'];`

and this is the html part
`<img src="mergedphoto/<?txt_idno?>.jpg">`

The image that is shown on the browser is not the source file one, anyone could help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to echo that variable, *for one thing*. Plus, the `txt_idno` is treated as a constant.

Comment: `<img src="mergedphoto/<?txt_idno?>.jpg">` need to be:- `<img src="mergedphoto/<?php echo $txt_idno?>.jpg">`

Comment: you can use this <img src="mergedphoto/<?=txt_idno?>.jpg"> like below

Answer (score 1):

you missed two this

1. you did not use echo which need to show php data
2. you missed $ sign

so update your code

```
<img src="mergedphoto/<?txt_idno?>.jpg">
```

to

```
<img src="mergedphoto/<?=$txt_idno?>.jpg">
```

or

```
<img src="mergedphoto/<?php echo $txt_idno?>.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$txt_idno = $_SESSION['txt_idno'];
```

and this is the html part

```
<img src="<?php echo mergedphoto . '/' . $imageone . '.jpg'; ?>">
```